# Submit form data in AngularJS without specifying POST Url

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js, ng-submit

I am trying to reset user password by sending a mail. On clicking the email the URL is like:

> http://localhost:3000/reset/d58d5b16323276a14494fbd6998b0bb9

and it shows the following form

```
extends ../layout

block content
  .col-sm-8.col-sm-offset-2
    form(method='POST')
      legend Reset Password
      input(type='hidden', name='_csrf', value=_csrf)
      .form-group
        label(for='password') New Password
        input.form-control(type='password', name='password', value='', placeholder='New password', autofocus=true)
      .form-group
        label(for='confirm') Confirm Password
        input.form-control(type='password', name='confirm', value='', placeholder='Confirm password')
      .form-group
        button.btn.btn-primary.btn-reset(type='submit')
          i.fa.fa-keyboard-o
          | Change Password
```

On clicking button, the server gets a POST request like `/reset/:token`.
This works fine. Now i want to achieve the same functionality in angular js.
I have a controller and the same form. I dont want to do a `$http.post()`. 
On clicking submit, the server should get a post request at /reset/:token.

Please tell me how to do this in AngularJS without `$http.post()`.

Comment: Add `action="/reset/{{ theToken }}"` to your form.

Comment: Adapt your router code so that the token is available in $routeParams or $stateParams. Or use $location to get the token.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes it can be read using $location. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is used for creating single page applications. Hence the best bet is to use `$http.post` which won't refresh the page and you won't divert form SPA paradigm. However if you don't want to use `$http.post` use jQuery/JavaScript to post the form, but that will cause a page refresh.

Comment: That is understood. But I am not able to understand why the above code works but when the same thing is tried in angular, it fails!!
@JB Nizet , i dont have the token as it is redirected from link sent to user email

Comment: what did u tired in angular, could you please share the error details and angularjs code